# How do I initialize an object of std::array<std::array<T, 2>, 2>?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, list-initialization

I'm trying to initialize objects of type thing:

```
template<typename T>
  struct thing : std::array<std::array<T, 2>, 2>
  {
  };

thing<int> t1 {{ {1,2}, {3,4} }};
```

I get:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘thing<int>::thing(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
 thing<int> t1 {{{1,2},{3,4}}};
```

Ditto with

```
thing<int> t0{{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }};
```

and several other things.

Comment: why are you tying to inherit from a 2D array?

Comment: If you're trying to alias the array, you'd better do `template <class T> using thing = std::array<T, 2>, 2>;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using a C++17 compiler, you're only missing an extra set of braces. The following [compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0f6e2e7ae6ba0e3):

```
thing<int> t1 { { { {1,2}, {3,4} } } };
//            | | | |- braces for inner array
//            | | |--- braces for outer array
//            | |----- braces for base sub object of thing
//            |------- braces for list initialization of thing
```

C++17 [modified](http://wg21.link/p0017) the rules for aggregates to allow base classes, as long as they're `public` and non-`virtual`.

From [*§11.6.1/1 [dcl.init.aggr]*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#1)

> An *aggregate* is an array or a class with
>       (1.1)
>       no user-provided, `explicit`, or inherited constructors ([class.ctor]),
>       (1.2)
>       no private or protected non-static data members ([class.access]),
>       (1.3)
>       no virtual functions, and
>       (1.4)
>       no virtual, private, or protected base classes ([class.mi]).

The base classes are now considered [*elements* of the aggregate](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#2), and can themselves be initialized using *list-initialization*.

> The *elements* of an aggregate are:
>       (2.1)
>       for an array, the array elements in increasing subscript order, or
>       (2.2)
>       for a class, the direct base classes in declaration order, followed by the direct non-static data members ([class.mem]) that are not members of an anonymous union, in declaration order.

---

***C++14, and earlier***, version of the answer follows:

`std::array` is an aggregate, and the initialization done using a braced-init-list is aggregate initialization. However, `thing` is not an aggregate because it has a base class.

From *§8.5.1/1 [dcl.init.aggr]*

> An *aggregate* is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), **no base classes** (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

Thus, aggregate initialization is not going to work. Depending on what you're attempting to do, you either want to provide a constructor for `thing` that takes an `std::array<std::array<T, 2>, 2>` argument, and initialize the base subobject

```
template<typename T>
struct thing : std::array<std::array<T, 2>, 2>
{
    thing(std::array<std::array<T, 2>, 2> arr) 
    : std::array<std::array<T, 2>, 2>(arr) 
    {}
};
thing<int> t{ {{ {{1,2}}, {{3,4}} }} };
```

Or have `thing` contain the `std::array` as a data member. Now `thing` is still an aggregate.

```
template<typename T>
struct thing
{
    std::array<std::array<T, 2>, 2> arr;
};
thing<int> t{ {{ {{1,2}}, {{3,4}} }} };
```

---

If what you're attempting to do is have `thing` be an alias for an `array<array<T,2>,2>`, then you don't need either of the above. Use

```
template<typename T>
using thing = std::array<std::array<T, 2>, 2>;

thing<int> t{{ {{1,2}}, {{3,4}} }};
```